# iOS Opening a ppt/pptx File from a Cordova App in Powerpoint

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, powerpoint, hybrid-mobile-app

I did a lot of research on this problem, but no solution worked for me. Now i have decided to ask myself. Also I am fairly new to the topic as a whole.

So what is my Problem? Actually it seems pretty easy. I got a cordova-app and i am also using Quasar v0.13 and the target is a Ipad with iOS 9+. In this App there is a Documentlist, where the User can first download a file and then open it. These Files (ppt/pptx) should then be opened in Powerpoint, when clicked on them, but they do not. I got it so far that Powerpoint opens, but then it throws an error where it just says that it cant open the file. In this error message it displays the correct Path to the file. 
And now i do not know anymore. So here is what i already tried:

**1. Using the fileOpener2-Plugin for cordova**

This Plugin actually works quite well. It opens the files, but it opens them in the app. So i read the documentation where it says that you can open files with another app by setting a second argument in the Open-Method. This second Argument has to be the MIME-Type of the app you want the file to open with. So i did this:

```
openItem: function (fullPath) {
return cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(fullPath,'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',{
  error : function(e) {
    console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
  },
  success : function () {
    console.log('file opened successfully');
  }
});}
```

I tried several MIME-Types but nothing happened. The files still got opened in my cordova app. There was no change in behavior and no error was logged. It just said "Opened file succesfully". So i checked the folder into which the files get downloaded. It is the **documentsDirectory** and other apps should be able to work with files stored in there, if i got that right. I did some research on that Problem, but no other solutions seem to help. The **fullPath-Variable** hast this structure: file:/// + path, as it is also shown in the cordova documentation.

So, because that did not work i tried to open the files via the cordova inAppBrowser.

**2. Using the the corodova InAppBrowser-Plugin**

After doing a bit more research i found out that a URL with the specific Powerpoint-Prefix could work. So it has to be something like "ms-powerpoint: + fileURL". Then i added the prefix to my cordova config.xml and the info.plist.

config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="ms-powerpoint:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="ms-powerpoint:*" />
</platform>
```

info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>ms-powerpoint</string>
</array>
```

I also used to the AppAvailability-plugin to check is the prefix is actually viable. Turned out that it is. So my code to open the InAppBrowser looks like this:

```
openItem: function (fullPath) {
const changedFullPath = "ms-powerpoint:ofv|u|" + fullPath;
const changedFullPathEncoded = "ms-powerpoint:" + encodeURIComponent(fullPath);
const shortFullPath = "ms-powerpoint:" + fullPath;
console.log('electron.shell.openItem: ' + fullPath);
console.log('electron.shell.openItem: ' + changedFullPath);
console.log('electron.shell.openItem: ' + changedFullPathEncoded);
console.log('electron.shell.openItem: ' + shortFullPath);
return cordova.InAppBrowser.open(changedFullPath, '_blank');}
```

This opened Powerpoint but with the error message i mentioned above. Powerpoint says that it cannot open the file. As you can see, i tried different versions of the URL. I tried the encoded filepath and expanding the Prefix and there was just one difference. When i tried the encoded version powerpoint printed the whole filepath in its error message. When it was not encoded only the filename was shown. In addition, when i used another argument than "_blank" powerpoint did not open, the same happened when i encoded the prefix.

So, that is it so far. I am pretty sure that i am making some dumb mistake, but i ran out of ideas. Perhaps i have to expand the URL a bit more? I really appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I experience that fileopener2 works well with android but take a look at this [plugin](https://github.com/ti8m/DocumentHandler/blob/master/README.md) for iOS.

Comment: @Jamwick did you get this figured out?  I am having a similar issue